# Image Display Error in WPF forms "No Imaging Component suitable to complete this operation was found."

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, image

I am I'm trying to display an image into a Image(Image Box) in WPF. but it doesn't display and the error says "no imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found." I also attached the image of my db. Please, anyone could help.

here's my db structure
table name: tbl_guestimage
Columns:
Name            Type
imageid         int(50)
wristbondguestcode  varchar(80)
image           longblob

heres my code:

```
string query3 = "SELECT image FROM tbl_guestimage WHERE wristbondguestcode =" +txtSearch.Text;
command = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
mdr = command.ExecuteReader();
if (mdr.Read())
{
    LblWristbondCode.Content = mdr["fullname"].ToString();
    byte[] data = (byte[])mdr["image"];

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
    var imageSource = new BitmapImage();
    imageSource.BeginInit();
    imageSource.StreamSource = ms;
    imageSource.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    imageSource.EndInit();
    guestimage.Source = imageSource;
        
}
```

[image]

I am trying to search in the web but still none could solve my problem.

Comment: `byte[] data` does apparently not contain a valid encoded bitmap frame like e.g. a JPEG or a PNG. The MemoryStream and BitmapImage code you are showing is ok, it would work with a valid encoded bitmap.

Comment: You need to show (or debug) the code you're using to save the images to the database. It's almost certainly the case that instead of storing the image data, the database contains a BLOB with the literal contents `System.Byte[]`. This could be happening due to using string concatenation to form the `INSERT` query instead of properly using named parameters (with the `MySqlParameter` type).

Comment: that's what I'm thinking too. but how? and do you have any idea what would i replace in convertion like BYTE[] data? @Clemens

Comment: I already save the image in the db, all i need to do is to retrieve it and display in a Image(Image box) in wpf. @BradleyGrainger

Comment: But how do you save the image? Perhaps show us that code. And use the debugger to find out what exactly is contained in `data`.

Comment: @MackyCute I am extremely confident that your current code does _not_ save the image in the database.

Comment: That is, there is a BLOB saved in the database, but it doesn't contain any image data. (That's why it can't be loaded.)

Comment: Here's the code in saving the image.

Comment: MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            int width = Convert.ToInt32(CaptureBox.Width);
            int height = Convert.ToInt32(CaptureBox.Height);
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
            CaptureBox.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height));
            bmp.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();    
            DBConfig.MysqlManager db = new DBConfig.MysqlManager(null,txtwristbondcode.Text, pic.ToString());
            db.addimage();

Comment: `pic.ToString()` is the bug. You can't save a `byte[]` to the database by converting it to a string. (And this particular `.ToString()` call will return `"System.Byte[]"` which is what is getting saved.)